# React input обновление последней буквы Есть ли изящное решение

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть React контрол с тегом `input`  и дочерний контрол обрабатывающий введенное значение.

```
<div>{this.state.Inputed}</div>
<input
    autoFocus
    type="text"
    value={this.state.Inputed}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
<Chaild Inputed={this.state.Inputed} />
```

Стандартный обработчик работает и  корректно отображает свойство в пределах этого контрола, но в дочерний контрол значение передается с опозданием на одну букву

```js
handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("Value from event:", event.target.value);
    this.setState({ Inputed: event.target.value }, () => {
        console.log("Value from State:", this.state.Inputed);
    });
}
```

после долгих мытарств обработчик написан так

```js
handleChange = async function (event) {
    await this.setState({ Inputed: event.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.Inputed);
    this.setState({ Inputed: this.state.Inputed });//повторно ввожу чтобы обновить дочерний контрол
}
```

Вопрос: есть ли какой ни будь стандартный способ бороться с таким поведением?

На мой взгляд это баг.

К примеру во Vue такой проблемы нет.

Answer (score 1):

Как вы правильно заметили, `setState` - это асинхронная операция. К тому же она не возвращает промис, поэтому писать перед её выполнением `await` бесcмысленно.

Если вы хотите посмотреть как изменился state после выполнения `setState`, то можно сделать так:

```js
handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("Value from event:", event.target.value);
    this.setState({ Inputed: event.target.value }, () => {
        console.log("Value from State:", this.state.Inputed);
    });
}
```

К тому же после изменения состояния в результате вызова `setState` выполняется перерисовка компонента и дочерних компонентов (в случае если что-то из state попадает в props к детям). Можно поставить вот такой эксперимент:

```js
handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("Value from event:", event.target.value);
    this.setState({ Inputed: event.target.value });
}

...

render() {
    console.log("Value from State:", this.state.Inputed);
    ...
}
```

И убедиться что консоль логи выполняются один за другим и выводят ожидаемое значение.

Comment: Вот в том то и дело что  после выполнения  this.setState({ Inputed: event.target.value }); свойство передается дочернему компоненту с задержкой в один символ. и только повторный вызов  this.setState исправляет эту ситуацию

Comment: Все разобралась. Я вызывала функцию обработки свойства в  функции  componentWillReceiveProps() то есть до обновления

Comment: @Евгения, красава! Что там было?